# fail2ban keeps saying that the IP is banned and then it says it is already banned

Tags: linux, iptables, webserver, fail2ban

Here is my fail2ban version v0.11.1  set up on a Ubuntu Linux 20.04 on an AWS EC2 planform.  The jail.local file has the standard defaults from jail.conf but I only activate these 2 jails in jail.local:

```
    # Stop the 404 attacks
    [apache-404]
    enabled = true
    port = http,https
    filter = apache-404
    logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log
    maxretry = 5
    findtime = 60
    bantime = 300
    action = iptables-multiport[name=HTTPS, port=https, protocol=tcp]


    [recidive]
    enabled =true
    logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
    banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
    bantime  = 5m
    findtime = 1d
```

The definition file for recidive is the one that comes with the fail2ban package.  The apache-404.conf  definition file  is the following:

```
    # Fail2Ban configuration file 
    [Definition]
    failregex = ^<HOST>.*"(GET|POST).*" (404|444|403|400) .*$ 
    ignoreregex =
```

When under test with repeated hits from the same user on an invalid file on our web site we see the following in the fail2ban.log file and it makes no sense to us why it does not ban the user, unless we are doing something incorrect in our configuration or our expectations are too high.

```
    2023-03-07 12:09:56,316 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:09:56
    2023-03-07 12:10:05,513 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:05
    2023-03-07 12:10:08,218 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:07
    2023-03-07 12:10:13,025 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:12
    2023-03-07 12:10:14,629 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:14
    2023-03-07 12:10:15,213 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: NOTICE  [apache-404] Ban 71.29.12.245
    2023-03-07 12:10:15,331 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [recidive] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:15
    2023-03-07 12:10:16,233 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:16
    2023-03-07 12:10:22,142 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:21
    2023-03-07 12:10:24,907 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:24
    2023-03-07 12:10:34,019 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:33
    2023-03-07 12:10:35,622 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:35
    2023-03-07 12:10:35,854 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: NOTICE  [apache-404] 71.29.12.245 already banned
    2023-03-07 12:10:37,521 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:10:37
    2023-03-07 12:11:25,901 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:25
    2023-03-07 12:11:33,912 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:33
    2023-03-07 12:11:35,630 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:35
    2023-03-07 12:11:37,245 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:37
    2023-03-07 12:11:37,343 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: WARNING [apache-404] 71.29.12.245 already banned
    2023-03-07 12:11:38,914 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:38
    2023-03-07 12:11:40,546 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:40
    2023-03-07 12:11:42,149 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:42
    2023-03-07 12:11:43,928 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:43
    2023-03-07 12:11:45,531 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:45
    2023-03-07 12:11:45,563 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: WARNING [apache-404] 71.29.12.245 already banned
    2023-03-07 12:11:47,140 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:46
    2023-03-07 12:11:48,126 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:48
    2023-03-07 12:11:51,324 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:51
    2023-03-07 12:11:53,258 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:53
    2023-03-07 12:11:54,337 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:54
    2023-03-07 12:11:54,585 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: WARNING [apache-404] 71.29.12.245 already banned
    2023-03-07 12:11:55,940 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:55
    2023-03-07 12:11:57,734 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:57
    2023-03-07 12:11:59,337 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:11:59
    2023-03-07 12:12:00,940 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:12:00
    2023-03-07 12:12:06,848 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 71.29.12.245 - 2023-03-07 12:12:06
    2023-03-07 12:12:07,414 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: WARNING [apache-404] 71.29.12.245 already banned
    2023-03-07 12:14:08,567 fail2ban.filter         [173661]: INFO    [apache-404] Found 198.199.97.240 - 2023-03-07 12:14:08
    2023-03-07 12:17:07,790 fail2ban.actions        [173661]: NOTICE  [apache-404] Unban 71.29.12.245
```

When I issues the following to iptables I get this:

```
     sudo iptables-save
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Mar  7 12:19:33 2023
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [92:8233]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [95:90339]
    :f2b-HTTPS - [0:0]
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 443 -j f2b-HTTPS
    -A f2b-HTTPS -j RETURN
    -A f2b-HTTPS -j RETURN
    -A f2b-HTTPS -j RETURN
    COMMIT
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing research and testing I was able to determine what the issues were that caused `fail2ban` to mistakenly identify an IP address as already banned when it was banned.

It turns out that the IP address was not banned at all because the `apache-404.conf` file was incorrectly set up. The Port defined in the action was set as just HTTPS but the user who triggered all this chaos was not using HTTPS.

Here is the proper set up (notice that it no longer shows action - just takes the default and that the ports are both HTTP and HTTPS):

```
    # Stop the 404 attacks
    [apache-404]
    enabled = true
    port = http,https
    filter = apache-404
    logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log
    maxretry = 5
    findtime = 60
    bantime = 300
```